# Documenting R.oo classes/methods with Roxygen

Tags: r, roxygen, roxygen2

Could someone point me to a good example of documenting R.oo classes/methods with Roxygen?  In R.oo, classes/methods are created by calls to setConstructorS3() and setMethodS3(), so there is no function to document per-se.  Do you simply create standard Roxygen function documentation, but place it on top of a NULL statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trial & error, here's what I came up with.  This solution ensures that all objects are exported properly, that R CMD build/check does not puke, that there is no redundant documentation, and that examples will execute.  Note that the solution won't work if @export is replaced with @method/@S3method.  Theoretically that should work, but it didn't for me.  Someone have a better solution?

```
#' Title.  More Info.
#'
#' @param someParam  Param info.
#'
#' @name     MyMethod
#' @export   MyMethod
NULL
#' @rdname   MyMethod
#' @name     MyMethod.ClassName
#' @export   MyMethod.ClassName
setMethodS3( "MyMethod" , "ClassName" , appendVarArgs = FALSE , 
function( this , someParam ) { ... } )
```

Answer (score 3):

I think,

1. `@usage` are needed.
2. A dot-dot-dot argument is needed in the `MyMethod.ClassName` function for S3 generic/method consistency.
3. Not `#' @export MyMethod.ClassName` but rather `#' @S3method MyMethod ClassName`?

An example code:

```
#' Title.  More Info.
#'
#' @usage MyMethod(...)
#' @param this this.
#' @param someParam Param info.
#' @param ... other arguments.
#'
#' @rdname   MyMethod
#' @export   MyMethod
#' @name     MyMethod
NULL

#' @usage \method{MyMethod}{ClassName}(this, someParam, ...)
#' @return MyMethod.ClassName:
#' \code{NULL}
#'
#' @rdname   MyMethod
#' @S3method MyMethod ClassName
#' @name     MyMethod.ClassName
setMethodS3("MyMethod", "ClassName", appendVarArgs = FALSE, 
function(this, someParam, ...) {
  NULL
})
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work.  R CMD check complains about undocumented parameters, even though they are documented.  In general I like your approach, except that it requires documenting "this" and "..." which might not be used in practice.

Comment: Thank you for your information.  I will try to write more appropriate examples some day.